# how to plot two variables in a bar graph plot

Tags: r, bar-chart

i need help with plotting the dataframe below in a bargraph which i'll add as well.

```
      Month       Base       Advanced
   2008-01-01  20.676043   20.358472
   2008-02-01  -57.908706  -62.368464
   2008-03-01  -3.130082   -5.876791
   2008-04-01  20.844747   14.162446
   2008-05-01  39.882740   42.315828
   2008-06-01  -12.802920  -13.333419
   2008-07-01  -49.299693  -39.843041
   2008-08-01  -4.563942   10.995445
   2008-09-01  -100.018700 -77.054218
   2008-10-01  -42.056913 -30.485998
```

My current code which isnt working great:

```
ggplot(ResidualsDataFrame,aes(x=Base,y=Advanced,fill=factor(Month)))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
scale_fill_discrete(name="Forecast",breaks=c(1, 2),     
labels=c("Base", "Advanced"))+
xlab("Months")+ylab("Forecast Error")
```

This is what I'm trying to make. 
Any help is kindly appreciated.

[image: Bar Graph Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick that helps is to change the data from "wide" to "long". Continuing with the `tidyverse` (since you're using `ggplot2`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

x %>%
  gather(ty, val, -Month)
#         Month       ty         val
# 1  2008-01-01     Base   20.676043
# 2  2008-02-01     Base  -57.908706
# 3  2008-03-01     Base   -3.130082
# 4  2008-04-01     Base   20.844747
# 5  2008-05-01     Base   39.882740
# 6  2008-06-01     Base  -12.802920
# 7  2008-07-01     Base  -49.299693
# 8  2008-08-01     Base   -4.563942
# 9  2008-09-01     Base -100.018700
# 10 2008-10-01     Base  -42.056913
# 11 2008-01-01 Advanced   20.358472
# 12 2008-02-01 Advanced  -62.368464
# 13 2008-03-01 Advanced   -5.876791
# 14 2008-04-01 Advanced   14.162446
# 15 2008-05-01 Advanced   42.315828
# 16 2008-06-01 Advanced  -13.333419
# 17 2008-07-01 Advanced  -39.843041
# 18 2008-08-01 Advanced   10.995445
# 19 2008-09-01 Advanced  -77.054218
# 20 2008-10-01 Advanced  -30.485998
```

So plotting it is a little simpler:

```
x %>%
  gather(ty, val, -Month) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Month, weight=val, fill=ty)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image: split barplot with dodging]

The data used:

```
x <- read.table(text='      Month       Base       Advanced
   2008-01-01  20.676043   20.358472
   2008-02-01  -57.908706  -62.368464
   2008-03-01  -3.130082   -5.876791
   2008-04-01  20.844747   14.162446
   2008-05-01  39.882740   42.315828
   2008-06-01  -12.802920  -13.333419
   2008-07-01  -49.299693  -39.843041
   2008-08-01  -4.563942   10.995445
   2008-09-01  -100.018700 -77.054218
   2008-10-01  -42.056913 -30.485998', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x$Month <- as.Date(x$Month, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. Im trying to plot it but its not working. What format should the ty column be in? currently its "chr" whilst val is "num".
Do I need to change the "chr" format to a different format in order to plot the data?

Comment: If you post `dput(head(dat))` (or whatever your data's variable name is), I might be able to see things not apparent in how you posted it the first time. `ty` should be `character`, as it is created by `tidyr::gather`; naming it "ty" was completely arbitrary and temporary, it was used solely to transform from wide to long. `val` is the higher-class of the two data columns (`Base`, `Advanced`), where `chr > num > int > lgl`, I hope they are both `num`.

Comment: yes, they are both num.

> dput(head(ResidualsDataFrame))
structure(list(Month = structure(c(13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 
14000, 14031), class = "Date"), mod = c("Base", "Base", "Base", 
"Base", "Base", "Base"), val = c(20.6760432566744, -57.9087058298989, 
-3.13008154971899, 20.8447473204268, 39.8827397785123, -12.8029198207723
)), .Names = c("Month", "mod", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I just cant seem to depict it the way you have in the sample graph above. R is not plotting my dataframe. 
I keep getting the following error message:
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_count()`:
invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to `gather` an already-`gather`ed object. In my code above, I showed `x %>% gather(...)` by itself to demonstrate what it was doing. Then, in the next code block, I'm assuming the `x` is still in the "wide" format, not the tall format as you just posted in your comment. With what you justed put in the comment, try the same plotting command *without* the `gather` command.

Comment: Lifesaver! it worked once i took the second gather command away. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would you know how i can adjust the colors of the bar graphs to the colors in the example i posted? as in just simple blue and red

Comment: That is one of the most frequently-asked questions about `ggplot2`, both on SO and elsewhere. I suggest starting with [cookbook-r](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/), they show a couple of techniques. Big picture: consider bringing color in as a column of the dataframe (via a merge/join operation), or setting the color palette.

Answer (score 0):

Without easy access to your data to reproduce this, all I can do is provide some examples from one of the datasets I work with, so hopefully this will be useful. Method 1: ts.plot; Method 2: Plotly; Method 3: ggplot.

Method 1: I want to plot V17 & V18 together:

```
ts.plot(c(data1t$V17), gpars=list(col=c("black"), ylab="msec")) # first series
lines(data1t$V18,col="red") # second
```

[image: Method 1]

Method 2: Plotly; V29 contains my x-coordinates for both V17 and V18

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=~data1t$V29, mode='lines') %>% 
   add_lines(y=~data1t$V17,
   line=list(color='rgb(205,12,24')) %>% 
   add_lines(y=~data1t$V18,
   line=list(color='rgb(12,24,205'))
```

[image: Method 2]

Method 3: ggplot; V29 contains my x-coordinates for both V17 and V18

```
data1t %>% arrange(V29) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=V29,y=value,color=variable)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=V17,col='spkts')) +
    geom_line(aes(y=V18,col='dpkts',
    alpha=0.5))
```

[image: Method 3]

Comment: Similarly, without access to *your* data (at least a sample of it), it is difficult to apply this to any other dataset.